# Calculate non constant but increasing darkness?

Tags: java

I have a small game which has height differences. When my character is on level 0 it is nicely bright, when it goes down to level -1 it becomes just a little darker, on level -2 it becomes a bit more darker. That's no problem.

In my case 0 is light and pitch black is 1, 0.5 is in this case not light and not dark.

The "flow" from light to dark is very constant, cause you simply add 0.1 for every level going down.

How can i make it so that after 0.5 is goes darker faster?

For example:

```
0: 0
-1: 0.1
-2: 0.2
-3: 0.3
-4: 0.4
-5: 0.5
-6: 0.65
-7: 0.80
-8: 1
```

The deeper the character goes the faster it will become darker.

I suspect there is a math function for this kind of things, but I'm not really into math. Can somebody give me a helping hand?

Comment: I think the equation in the accepted answer will suit you nicely: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384613/exponential-function-with-values-between-0-and-1-for-x-values-between-0-and-1

Comment: "I'm not really into math." You'll find game programming to be rather painful.

Comment: @bajada93 that made my brain hurt ;-) David previous game did well, it really depends on the type of game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get dark more quickly the deeper you go, I'd use the function `light = c * Math.pow(-level, n)`

`n` is a number that you pick to determine how fast you want to drop off. At *n = 1,* the light will drop at a constant rate as you descend, while bigger numbers drop off more quickly the deeper you descend. For example, when *n = 1.5,* the light drops about 5% on the first step, and 17% on the last. (Numbers less than one cause the light to drop quickly at first, and more slowly as you descend.)

The number `c` is a function of what you choose for n; `c = Math.pow(-LEVEL_MIN,-n)`. In your example, the `LEVEL_MIN` is -8, but if you want to go deeper, you'd change this to -10 or whatever.

Answer (score 4):

i have another approach for you, please read:

1)assume, there are 10 levels, you have 10 shades of brightness that is 0.1 to 1

2) instead.of dividing 10 shades of brightness into 10 parts, divide them into 20 parts to get each part as 0.05.

3) first 5 stages the darkness increases by 0.05, so by the time you reach stage 5, you are 0.05*5=0.25.hence, each step is 0.05 upto level 5.

4)the remaining that is 1-0.25=0.75 , is to be covered in the next 5 steps, so darkness will increase by 0.75/5=0.15. hence.from stage 5 to 10, darkness will increase by 0.15.

5) in my sample, i chose 10, you could choose 8 and probably do 1/8 or probably 1/16.
hope this helped!!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding a constant value of `0.1` on each step, you could introduce a member field to your class that represents how much to add.  Then you can update the value once it reaches `.5`

```
class GameState { 

   int value;
   int changeValue = 0.1;

   public void applyLevelChange() {
       value += changeValue;
       if(value >= .5) {
          changeValue = .15;
       } else if (value >= .8) {
          changeValue = .20;
       }   
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a member field? Isnt it sufficient to change `changeValue = .15` to `value += .15` and omit the `value += changeValue` line and the field (still keeping the if-else)?

Comment: I think it's a little more readable this way, but you're right its not 'needed' per say

Answer (score 2):

Try to find function, which rises more and more slowly:
An example:

```
arctg(a)
```

lets see how it looks:
[Graph atan(a)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arctg%28a%29)
but it raises to `PI/2` for x-> + infinity
So it needs function where `f(-8)=1`
It is ok with this function
 [Better graph -atan(a)/atan(8)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-arctg%28a%29%2Farctg%288%29)
Hope this helps

Comment: That's the one i was looking for, did some research on neural networks and they used similar functions for seed if i remember correctly. Cheers to the others for their helpful replies and hints!

Comment: He asked for a function that rises more quickly, not more slowly. But he accepted this answer? Nothing makes sense.

Comment: @erickson I haven't yet gave the solution a try, but i suspect that one of the many other functions will have the correct result, or i can simple inverse the function result. But of course when i implement it tomorrow i can always post a follow up or try one of the many other solutions (including yours). At this time such function looked the way to go, but when implementing it i may be wrong or right.

Answer (score 2):

Your first 5 line up with the expression

```
darkness = -0.1 * level;
```

So there's a start.

Now, for every level over 5 we want to add more.  How much more?  Well it seems like by level -8 you want the more to be 0.2 so 0.2/3

```
darkness = ( -0.1 * level ) + ( Math.max(0, level - 5) * -0.2/3 * level )
```

You'll need to make sure all values are floats or doubles or you may get integer truncation.